# Missing spark plug, broken rear timing chain guide?

Tags: sparkplugs, spark

On a 2004 ford explorer v6. I had a mechanic tell me the rear timing chain guide went.
Upon getting my vehicle to the house I noticed a single spark plug sitting on the front deck on the plastic gutter piece, and looked at the engine to find a spark plug wire hanging free with an empty spark plug hole.
They told me they did the work I asked, and had it running, then it began to sound odd and stopped running.
Is it possible they screwed up?

Comment: It seems clear they screwed up by returning the car to you with a missing spark plug. I'd find another mechanic!

Comment: If you were missing a plug your engine should have been running extremely rough, did you notice this?

Comment: Yes all six are necessary, there are no spares.  I'd take it back and demand a refund.  I don't think I would give them another chance to "fix" it.

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly an issue on their side.
A spark plug does not blow out of the engine alone, the spark plug would be shattered at minimum.

Get the best refund you can, reinstall the spark plug and try a different mechanic.

What I don't understand  is that you have been able to drive back home like this ?!